# Display UIAlertViewController in Gamescene?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift2, uialertview

So apparently GameScene cannot .presentViewController, so here's what I did.

```
let msg="Congrats... You died!\n"+"Score: "+String(score)
                let myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: msg, message: "Try Again?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
                    UIAlertAction in
                    self.timer.invalidate() //timer is not properly invalidating... it multple bacteria spawn... eevery 10 seconds with t difference ~0.5 seconds <-- FIXED as of 2/29/16
                    self.timer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnBacteria"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                    self.spawnBacteria()
                    score=0
                  //  print("FIRE")
                }
                myAlert.addAction(okAction) 
                // _______________

                self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, it appears that this does not work for multiple views, and I would like to add another view for the menu of my game. So, how can I create this UIAlertViewController and add it onto the GameScene? Any help is much appreciated.
NOTE: I am aware that an identical question was asked, however I do not understand the answer, and I don't know where to place the pieces of code provided in the answer, so please don't dismiss this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSAlertView](https://github.com/sspbond007/JSAlertView) which display alert using old/new API depending on running iOS version. This displays alert over window, so you need not to worry about the view/navigation hierarchy.

Hope this will help.